# Can I omit delegates declaration in .m files

Tags: ios, objective-c

Should I duplicate delegates declaration in the `@interface ()` block like this:

**.h file**

```
@interface VKStartScreen : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate, VKSdkUIDelegate>

@end
```

**.m file**

```
@interface VKStartScreen () <UIAlertViewDelegate, VKSdkUIDelegate>

@end
```

Or can I just omit it in the .m file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can omit in either file. You only need it in one place. I personally put the delegate declarations in the .m unless some other classes need to know that this class conforms to these protocols. Always opt for private and if it needs to be public for some reason open it up.